# jquery lightgallery have a url to another page in the caption?

Tags: jquery, html, lightgallery

I'm trying to add a URL to a caption in the light galley, but the light gallery image itself is a link, so the caption URL needs to go outside of the light gallery URL, even when I do this just as a test. the page isn't loaded and light gallery just opens with the question mark image

simply put I'm trying to add an edit button to the caption that opens my edit page and doesn't open the light gallery

Thanks

EDIT Generated HTML
html:

```
<ul id="lightgallery">           
    <li data-src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/site_images/LI02after.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=aoEeOyzRvvKSaUQWY91Wo2dM3Rw%3D&amp;Expires=1570626218" data-sub-html="Photo - LI-02 - 04 Oct 2019">
        <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/CACHE/images/site_images/LI02after/76c89641ae7d8363a906f69bde6c72f4.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=VUWPRLyh9xHB3liRDnLEuH7cBo8%3D&amp;Expires=1570626218">
            <div class="lightb-gallery-poster">
                <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/zoom.png">
            </div>
        </a>
        <h5 class="text-white">Photo - LI-02<br><small class="text-muted">04 Oct 2019</small></h5>
        <a class="pull-right" href="/sites/edit_file/272/1/">
            <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li data-src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/site_images/YO-05_after.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=oNrlgZ%2FaySqHhK8X91E3M%2BE69U0%3D&amp;Expires=1570626219" data-sub-html="Photo - YO-05 - 04 Oct 2019">
        <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/CACHE/images/site_images/YO-05_after/ec68229ca57c5a4b25973a7f73c59bc1.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=6qsiNXCMi0l00DxmtbUMEnQOlSY%3D&amp;Expires=1570626219">
            <div class="lightb-gallery-poster">
                <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/zoom.png">
            </div>
        </a>
        <h5 class="text-white">Photo - YO-05<br><small class="text-muted">04 Oct 2019</small></h5>
        <a class="pull-right" href="/sites/edit_file/273/1/">
            <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li data-src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/site_images/DE-02-SW-03.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=YIkANh1aRvDm4ty5zuFcbDFG4Es%3D&amp;Expires=1570626219" data-sub-html="Photo - DE-02 - 04 Oct 2019">
        <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://application.s3.amazonaws.com/media/CACHE/images/site_images/DE-02-SW-03/35834b2b2713098a83758b7e82f3c777.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&amp;Signature=p3LPMdWDhRkzetPCwPTNcxT%2Fyfs%3D&amp;Expires=1570626219">
            <div class="lightb-gallery-poster">
                <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/zoom.png">
            </div>
        </a>
        <h5 class="text-white">Photo - DE-02<br><small class="text-muted">04 Oct 2019</small></h5>
        <a class="pull-right" href="/sites/edit_file/274/1/">
            <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

lightgallery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
    thumbnail:true,
});
</script>
```

Comment: Since it is a front-end issue, it would be best if you added the generated HTML, not the Blade one. The CSS and JavaScript for the carousel too.

Comment: Have you tried using `event.stopPropagation()` on the edit button? This might work if the generated link of the light gallery is the parent element of the thumbnail. Would really help if you show the generated html markup.

Comment: ive added the rendered html to the question now

Comment: Are you unable to use a CSS selector (e.g. `<a href="img/img2.jpg" data-sub-html="#caption2">`) as per the documentation? I just tried in a Codepen and it worked for me.

Comment: im not sure what you mean? its the URL for editing the file which im having issues with, in the thumbnail, If the edit icon is clicked it just opens the gallery and not the edit page thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a kludge but you can make the edit links work via JS `onclick`:

```
<a onclick="document.location.href='/sites/edit_file/272/1/'; return false;" class="pull-right" href="/sites/edit_file/272/1/">
  <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true">asdf</i>
</a>
```

Comment: @AlexW If this works for you please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the accepted solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your image URLs are wrong you have to **"copy image location"** instead of "copy link location".

You can clearly check your images link and see that it's not working or open to public. If you have an api or access key that another story. but as far as the link. It is not a "open to public" link.

I tried your code in codepen and only changed the urls and it all start working.

[image]

for example change the `li data-src` and `img src` of one of the list items to this:

https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG

and you will see that it starts working.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here - I believe OP wants to add `<a>` elements to the image captions. Also, just because the image URLs don't directly end with the file extension (jpg, png) that doesn't mean they're invalid. Sometimes URL parameters are included for things like authentication and cache control (hence the parameters `&AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&Expires=1570626218`).

Comment: Yes but when I change the urls from OP code to my image urls it all start working. and second point the OP data-sub is not a URL also